# No se puede encontrar parte de la ruta + could not find a part of the path

Tags: asp.net, servidor, reportviewer, hosting

Gente! mediante la siguiente linea

```
Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Presentacion\reportes\AtencionesXProfXFecha.rdlc"
```

Le digoque reporte abrir a mi Reportviewer, el problema radica en que en un servidor local si me anda mientras que en el otro no y me da el error

```
Could not find a part of the path
```

alguna recomendacion sobre como resolver esto?
Muchas Gracias.!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con :

```
Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Presentacion/reportes/AtencionesXProfXFecha.rdlc")
```

Así evitaras que en ocasiones y dependiendo del entorno de deployment no sea posible resolver la ubicacion de un recurso.

```
Server.MapPath("~/")
```

Resuelve en tiempo de ejecucion al root path de tu sitio web, de ahi en adelante puedes usar una ubicación relativa a tu root site.

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco mas tu solucion?